# returning invalid directory on save c#

Tags: c#

I want to save a loaded picture to a certain directory but it keeps returning invalid director. Here's the code I'm using

```
if (OpenCdb != null)
{
    string pics = Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenCdb.FileName);
    // Save card image
    ImageResizer.SaveImage(CardImg.Image, pics + "\\pics\\" + cardid + ".jpg", 177, 254);
    //Save card thumbnail
    ImageResizer.SaveImage(CardImg.Image, pics + "\\pics\\thumbnail\\" + cardid + ".jpg", 44, 64);
}
```

I have tested the `pics` string and its returning the right directory so i don't know what else to do. I can also post the imageresizer function code if you need me too but it's a lot of code that's why I didn't add it in the question.

edit heres a pic of the error
[image]

```
    public static void SaveImage(Image image, string savedName, int width = 0, int height = 0)
    {
        Image originalImage = image;
        string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + savedName;

        if (width > 0 && height > 0)
        {
            Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback =
            new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
            Image imageToSave = originalImage.GetThumbnailImage
                (width, height, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
            imageToSave.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        else
        {
            originalImage.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it keeps returning invalid directory"? What returns what value? And what is OpenCdb? You haven't provided nearly enough context here.

Comment: Have you tried with `Path.Combine()` ? On which line does the error occur when debugging with breakpoints?

Comment: What do you expect? What do you get? ...and where?

Comment: edited with a pic of the error

Comment: Is "cardid" simply a numeric identifier? Could it possibly contain illegal characters?

Comment: You get a directory name then append another directory to it, is that what you wanted?

Comment: card id is a textbox on the form i already have the code check if its invalid and return an error msg if it is

Comment: i want to save the picture in the pics directory of where the opened file is

Comment: Do you mean "cardid" is a variable to which you have assigned the value of a textbox on the form or, what you've typed, that it IS a textbox?

Comment: I don't think you need the path get directory name, edit are the slashes the right way?

Comment: the slashes are right and cardid is a string that is set to the contents of a textbox on the form

Comment: (can you show us the `filepath`)Are you getting the `filepath` right?  I think this may be like `filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + savedName`

Comment: Possibility to raise this exception is due to invalid 'filePath'. Rather than using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + savedName, try using System.IO.Path.Combine instead.

Comment: i just tested the path and its returning the right path i will upload the code in the image this is the path being returned C:\Users\hp owner\Desktop\OutlawPro\pics\thumbnail\1234567890.jpg

Comment: @outlaw1994  its working perfectly on mines!

Comment: @7-isnotbad how do you have it set up

Comment: @outlaw1994 nothing done more , wait i vl be back

Comment: nevermind everyone i got it to work the error was right in plainview i will post my fix as an answer for other people thanks everyone for your help

Comment: Your "fix" is identical to the answer below? you changed `filePath = savedName`, which was answered below...

Comment: pretty much yeah i just saw your updated answer i will accept it and upvote it thanks

Comment: Actually @Zec was the first to point in that direction :)

Comment: @outlaw1994  By late got answer !!!! check out mines!

Comment: Haters gonna hate. Thanks, Jesper. :)

Comment: yeah i upvoted him as well i dont know how i overlooked it honestly my app used to have to be in a the games directory to run so that why the code was like that this was the part to making it run outside in its own directory which is what i wanted now it runs both ways :D

Comment: i upvoted everyone who answered as you were all right the only reason i selected jester as accepted answer was because he went into more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind everyone i got it to work here was the code i ended up using

```
    public static void SaveImage(Image image, string savedName, int width = 0, int height = 0)
    {
        Image originalImage = image;
        string filePath = savedName;

        if (width > 0 && height > 0)
        {
            Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback =
            new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
            Image imageToSave = originalImage.GetThumbnailImage
                (width, height, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
            imageToSave.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        else
        {
            originalImage.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```

..

```
 public void SaveImage(string cardid)
    {
        if (LoadedImage != "")
        {
            if (OpenCdb != null)
            {
                string pics = Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenCdb.FileName);
                // Save card image
                ImageResizer.SaveImage(CardImg.Image, pics + "\\pics\\" + cardid + ".jpg", 177, 254);
                //Save card thumbnail
                ImageResizer.SaveImage(CardImg.Image, pics + "\\pics\\thumbnail\\" + cardid + ".jpg", 44, 64);
            }
            else
            {
                string pics = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                // Save card image
                ImageResizer.SaveImage(CardImg.Image,
                        pics + "pics\\" + cardid + ".jpg", 177, 254);
                //Save card thumbnail
                ImageResizer.SaveImage(CardImg.Image,
                       pics + "pics\\thumbnail\\" + cardid + ".jpg", 44, 64);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The path you're attempting to save to is made up like so:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenCdb.FileName) + "\\pics\\" + cardid + ".jpg"
```

There's every chance the result looks something like "C:\blahC:\meh\pics\something.jpg"

Comment: i just tested it and this is the path thats being returned which is the right path  C:\Users\hp owner\Desktop\OutlawPro\pics\thumbnail\1234567890.jpg

Comment: But... it's in the pic. "filePath" is the concatenation of BaseDirectory and savedName. savedName is built in the code sample as starting with the GetDirectoryName of OpenCdb.FileName.

Comment: @outlaw1994 - The path that is being returned from where? Is that the value of filePath or savedName? Or is it the result of concatenating them?

Comment: the path was the value of pics with the added values im looking at the code in the image now

Comment: @Zec i never hates ! :D  So +1

Answer (score 2):

I guess something is wrong with one or more of your strings.

1. use Path.Combine e.g. `Path.Combine(pics, "pics", cardid + ".jpg")` and `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, savedName)`

Also, i would combine the whole path before using it like:

`string fullPath = Path.Combine(pics, "pics", cardid + ".jpg")`

**UPDATE**

As stated below, the paths getting mixed up..
You set pics like this:

`string pics = Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenCdb.FileName);`

Which will result in `pics = C:\something\something`

and then you call `SaveImage` like this:

`SaveImage(CardImg.Image, pics + "\\pics\\" + cardid + ".jpg", 177, 254);`

And in that method you now set `pics = savedName` and the full path will then be:

`string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + savedName;`

Which is C:\somethingelse\C:\something\something

Answer (score 1):

**wow  i again created the situation and found back the solution**

**Solution is here**

**Step 1:** (not needed but a better way of prevention)

> add   Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)); to SaveImage as below

```
  public static void SaveImage(Image image, string savedName, int width = 0, int height = 0)
    {
        Image originalImage = image;
        string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + savedName;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
.
.
. The Rest code
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

**Step 2:**

```
if (OpenCdb != null)
{
    string pics ="";// no need of this (this  is the problem) Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenCdb.FileName);
```

> Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenCdb.FileName); wil return something like C:*** you are again combinig with  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory  in SaveImage this is the problem

```
    // Save card image
    ImageResizer.SaveImage(CardImg.Image, pics + "\\pics\\" + cardid + ".jpg", 177, 254);
    //Save card thumbnail
    ImageResizer.SaveImage(CardImg.Image, pics + "\\pics\\thumbnail\\" + cardid + ".jpg", 44, 64);
}
```